# How to bring setup wizard back in visual studio?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

I have created a setup project for my application in visual studio via setup wizard. Now I want to modify the installer and add some resources but I can't find how. Is there a way to bring the wizard back to add some resource files to it?

Comment: Could you show what you have tried?

Comment: I right clicked on my solution and chose Add->New project. Then from other language types->setup and deployment->visual studio installer I chose setup wizard. A wizard was opened in which I could modify the installer and add resources to it. Now that I have created the installer project, I can't bring that wizard back to modify it.